# Is it possible to change javascript variable values while debugging in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I'm debugging a javascript app (using Chrome dev tools), and I would like to change some variable values while stepping through the code.

Is that possible at all?

I have tried and got something like:

```
> modeline
1
> modeline=0
0             <<< seems to work but... 
> modeline
1             <<< ups!!
```

But I'm unable to find any documentation that states what can or can't be done...

Comment: Post some code. Where does `modeline` comes from?

Comment: @Emil: Is that important? modeline is a global variable, I also have tried modifying it using window.modeline with same results. But this question is also relevant to local variables declared inside a function

Comment: I do this frequently without issue.  Could some outside function be modifying your variable?  Try setting a breakpoint everywhere in the code where it is changed.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. Modifying a property on a JS object in Chrome does not seem to have any effect on the actual value of the object in the interpreter. In Firefox the same modification makes the js script evaluate differently as you would expect. Some kind of exstra security in Chrome peraps? Does anyone know if it can be turned of in Chrome, so you can use it for debugging js?

Comment: Filed a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=163207) for this.

Comment: Already implemented in V8: [Issue 2399](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2399) Now Chromium's Developer Tools need to be updated: [Issue 124206](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124206)

Comment: 2016/01/19  Chrome latest, trivial code (`var a = 1; debugger;  console.log(a);`) this bug is still present...

Comment: Still seeing this problem in Version 49.0.2623.110 m

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Why is this answer still getting upvotes?

Per [Mikaël Mayer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24694804/361684), this is no longer a problem, and my answer is obsolete (`go()` now returns `30` after mucking with the console).  This was fixed in July 2013, according to the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124206) linked above in [gabrielmaldi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603021/is-it-possible-to-change-javascript-variable-values-while-debugging-in-google-ch/4949829#comment22050829_4603021).  It alarms me that I'm still getting upvotes - makes me think the upvoter doesn't understand either the question or my answer.

I'll leave my original answer here for historical reasons, but **go upvote [Mikaël's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24694804/361684) instead**.

---

The trick is that you can't change a local variable directly, but you can modify the properties of an object.  You can also modify the value of a global variable:

```
var g_n = 0;
function go()
{
    var n = 0;
    var o = { n: 0 };
    return g_n + n + o.n;  // breakpoint here
}
```

console:

```
> g_n = 10
  10
> g_n
  10
> n = 10
  10
> n
  0
> o.n = 10
  10
> o.n
  10
```

Check the result of `go()` after setting the breakpoint and running those calls in the console, and you'll find that the result is 20, rather than 0 (but sadly, not 30).

Comment: 2016/01/19 Chrome latest, trivial code (var a = 1; debugger; console.log(a);) the bug is still present...

Comment: @Offirmo - `1` is logged. What is the bug? What did you expect to be logged?

Comment: with the debugger open, change the value of `a` to anything (ex. 42) in the "scope" panel then resume : 1 is logged

Comment: @Offirmo - not for me:  [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QEe5P.png).  But, if I wrap it in a function, then I see what you describe.  Interesting.  But then, I can change the value by entering it in the console directly, (which I personally find easier than using the scope panel).  [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mr85r.png)  I guess I never tried changing values in the scope panel.  I always just execute expressions in the console that change the value, and that seems to work no matter what.

Comment: `Why is this answer still getting upvotes?`because trying to modify large minified javascript files that can’t be pretty printed doesn’t works ?

Comment: I upvoted because your answer meets all the criteria of ["a good answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) *and* you mention another answer that provides newer, better info, which — coming from an accepted answer — gives it instant credibility. So, thanks. And enjoy the upvotes!

Comment: [Tyler Collier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50577313/641833) is more up to date than Mikaël Mayer's.  Maybe it is time for another edit?

Comment: Agreed. I added the same header.

Answer (score 71):

## Why is this answer still getting upvotes?

There is a better answer than this one after all these years, and I approve it since I'm using it all the time.
Go upvote [Tyler Collier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50577313/1287856)'s answer instead. They explain that you can either modify values in the console or in the stack trace. No need for a trick.

---

## Obsolete answer

This is now possible in chrome 35 (today as of July 11, 2014). I don't know which version allowed it first though.

Just tested @gilly3 example on my machine and it works.

- Open the console, in `Sources` and the tab `Snippets`, add a new snippet, paste the following code into it:

  `var g_n = 0; function go() { var n = 0; var o = { n: 0 }; return g_n + n + o.n;  // breakpoint here }`
- Right-click the snippet name, click 'Run' (this does not fire the function though)
- Add the breakpoint at the return statement.
- In the console below, type `go()`
- and change the variable values as  demonstrated below

[image: function with local modification allowed.]

and the returned result `g_n + n + o.n` is 30.

Comment: The regression of this bug is tracked in [the link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124206) provided in [Brian's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15842124/772086).

Comment: Chrome won't let me set a breakpoint in the snippet.

Answer (score 39):

Yes! Finally! I just tried it with Chrome, Version 66.0.3359.170 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Mac.

You can change the values in the scopes as in the first picture, or with the console as in the second picture.

[image: Chrome debugger change values]

[image]

Comment: That seems to work for complex situations (like Intervals and triggers) as well.

Comment: Updating via the console also works for me on Firefox version 100.01 (64-bit).

Comment: Is it possible to add a new property to the object?

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov I'm only able to by typing in the console, but I noticed some things. 1) The change was not reflected in the debugger UI (in the picture, I'm talking about where the arrow is pointing). 2) I was not able to add a property in the debugger UI. 3) If I changed the value of a variable in the debugger to a new literal, it would not show any of the properties. For example, if, next to `addend2`, I changed it to e.g. `{ val: 7 }`, `addend2` would then show as `Object`, with an "expand" arrow, but no properties shown. I'm on Version 120.0.6099.71 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Linux.

Answer (score 8):

This is an acknowledged bug in the Chrome Dev Tools:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124206

Comment: Looks like it was fixed Mar 21, 2013. I'm not sure how to tell which version of chrome it will be in.

Comment: @David They fixed it in Blink, we might have to wait for some time to get a Chrome build which uses Blink

Comment: It's broken (again) in in Chrome version 49.0.2623.87. Sign into the above link and star the issue if you want to elevate its importance.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like not.

Put a breakpoint, when it stops switch to the console, try to set the variable. It does not error when you assign it a different value, but if you read it after the assignment, it's unmodified. :-/

Comment: Ok... at least you are seeing the same behaviour that I see. But... Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Firebug seems to allow you to do that.

Comment: And so does IE and Opera Dragonfly.

Comment: I really miss Opera Dragonfly -____-

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to modify a script variable value by assignment in the Console.  Seems simplest.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a workaround.  Copy the entire method, modify it's name, e.g. originalName() to originalName2() but modify the variable inside to take on whatever value you want, or pass it in as a parameter.

Then if you call this method directly from the console, it will have the same functionality but you will be able to modify the variable values.

If the method is called automatically then instead type into the console

```
originalName = null;
function originalName(original params..)
{
    alert("modified internals");
    add whatever original code you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could change variable values with success (in addition to doing it in console window) is modifying the script directly in the chrome editor under "Sources" Tab (this changes the behavior of your script until you refresh the page), but that changes will be lost when a browser refresh, so be careful.
NOTE: This works also if you want to modify any line of code of your script but it doesn't work with typescript files coming from Angular projects.

Answer (score 1):

**To modify a value every time a block of code runs without having to break execution flow**:

The "Logpoints" feature in the debugger is designed to let you log arbitrary values to the console without breaking. It evaluates code inside the flow of execution, which means you can actually use it to change values on the fly without stopping.

Right-click a line number and choose "Logpoint," then enter the assignment expression. It looks something like this:

[image]

I find it super useful for setting values to a state not otherwise easy to reproduce, without having to rebuild my project with debug lines in it. REMEMBER to delete the breakpoint when you're done!

Comment: It doesn't modify the existing variable, just evaluates the expression.

Answer (score 1):

I do this differently than any of the other answers if I'm dealing with code that gets hit a lot (React render cycles).

1. Make a conditional breakpoint.
2. In the breakpoint condition, set your value `flags.showAccountCard = false;` -- the value will be set every time that breakpoint is hit.
3. However if you use `flags.showAccountCard = true;` the breakpoint will be hit every time because the engine is returning the value that it was set to (`true`) and that value means the breakpoint should be hit. To get around this add `false` on the same line: `flags.showAccountCard = true; false;`. This will set the value to `true` but not actually stop on the breakpoint.

This will allow you to set a value every time the exec pointer hits that line without stopping execution.

Tested in Chrome 99.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, went to the 'About Google Chrome'->Help and it said I needed to restart my browser to get the latest updates.

I did this, and suddenly, I can now change local variables.
Simply click the variable you want to edit in the Scope Variables window, and type in your new value.

I did notice some oddities though, that I had to step over some unrelated var assignments before I could alter the text in the right hand window (Scope Variables).

Comment: If you've used local storage to store properties, you can also go to Resources->LocalStorage and edit the properties you have saved directly there.