# Editing a JS variable from Firefox console

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

I know this is possible in Chrome's console (`F12`), simply by double clicking e.g. an element in an array and typing a new value. Here's a screenshot from Chrome illustrating such an edit:
[image: editing directly in Chrome console]

In Firefox, this functionality doesn't seem to work, as double clicking an element doesn't activate a cursor.

Can this be enabled somehow? Or is there a place where all variables are listed and editable? The related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603021/is-it-possible-to-change-javascript-variable-values-while-debugging-in-google-ch) I found focus on the debugger mode and Chrome, whereas I'm interested in editing values in a fully loaded page in Firefox.

Comment: You can click the `Array` itself, then on the right side edit the individual entries.

Comment: @Xufox Thought so too... but i just tested. clicking on it does not expant details on the right site. Maybe it does not work in the new FF.

Comment: @Xufox @Roland Confirmed: I tried clicking on both the hyperlinked `Array` and individual entries, but they don't become editable. Was there previously some new panel opening on the "right side"? Any ideas on an alternative for FF57?

Comment: why don't you change the variable programmatically? like `my_array[1] = "bar changed programmatically"`

Comment: @randomguy04 true, that would work, but I have a rather large array with small bits to edit, it is actually more convenient to click and edit a specific place in the array than programmatically calling that place. But if the feature really isn't available anymore, that's what I'll do I suppose.

Comment: @randomguy04 because it is not in scope :( it is a function-local one